# 16.04, nautilus problems and no files on desktop

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus

After last dist-upgrade my unity is work but I can't open folder (or start nautilus by term), and my desktop dosn't contain any file or folder, or accept click on it.

This is the error on launch nautilus by term:
`sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
No module named requests`

Comment: PyGI warning isn't very important. I get it all the time, yet my Nautilus works. No module requests part is more interesting, never seen that.

Comment: on sudo nautilus: `(nautilus:6698): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
No module named requests`

Comment: Same problem, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Python requests and Nautilus GI with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-requests python-requests \
gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 python-gi
```